# Cant access fetched elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, d3.js

i want to sort fetched data via estimated population values. But when i fetch the data and map the names and numbers objects to a new array, i can't even access a single object in the array.

Already tried mapping/converting it with lodash, Array.from(), copying with spread operator,...

Can please someone explain me why? Thanks.

**Code:**

```
d3 = require("d3")
_ = require("lodash")

const countries = []
const data = d3.tsv("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@1/world/110m.tsv")
    .then(d => d.map( c => {
        countries.push({
            name: c.name,
            pop_est: +c.pop_est
        })
        return countries
    }))

console.log(countries) // --> i get the array of objects 

let a = countries[0]
console.log(a) // undefined

console.log(countries.sort((a, b) => b.pop_est - a.pop_est)) // doesn´t sort
```

**Console output:**

```
[]
0: {name: "Kosovo", pop_est: 1804838}
1: {name: "Somaliland", pop_est: 3500000}
2: {name: "N. Cyprus", pop_est: 265100}
3: {name: "Afghanistan", pop_est: 28400000}
4: {name: "Angola", pop_est: 12799293}
5: {name: "Albania", pop_est: 3639453}
6: {name: "United Arab Emirates", pop_est: 4798491}
7: {name: "Argentina", pop_est: 40913584}
8: {name: "Armenia", pop_est: 2967004}
9: {name: "Antarctica", pop_est: 3802}
10: {name: "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands", pop_est: 140}
```

```
undefined
```

```
0: {name: "Kosovo", pop_est: 1804838}
1: {name: "Somaliland", pop_est: 3500000}
2: {name: "N. Cyprus", pop_est: 265100}
3: {name: "Afghanistan", pop_est: 28400000}
4: {name: "Angola", pop_est: 12799293}
5: {name: "Albania", pop_est: 3639453}
6: {name: "United Arab Emirates", pop_est: 4798491}
7: {name: "Argentina", pop_est: 40913584}
8: {name: "Armenia", pop_est: 2967004}
9: {name: "Antarctica", pop_est: 3802}
10: {name: "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands", pop_est: 140}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue regarding JavaScript `hoisting` and being single threaded by nature.

you need to add your code inside of your callback

```
const data = d3.tsv("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@1/world/110m.tsv")
    .then(d => d.map( c => {
        countries.push({
            name: c.name,
            pop_est: +c.pop_est
        })
     console.log(countries) // --> i get the array of objects 

      let a = countries[0]
      console.log(a) // undefined

      console.log(countries.sort((a, b) => b.pop_est - a.pop_est)) // doesn´t sort
    }))
```

`.then` in javascript is a promise you'll want to read about those